# How to use rdtsc in c#?

Tags: c#, c++, stopwatch, rdtsc

I'm working on a performance counter, which will be always running inside the app, ever a release version. So, it needs  to be as fast as possible.

I did compare c#'s `StopWatch` and c++ `rdtsc()`, and with 100 000 000 cycles taking 3 secs `rdtsc()` is a clear winner vs 23 seconds that `StopWatch` needs.

My problem is that I only know how to call `rdtsc()` from c++.

Can anyone suggest if there is a standard way to do it, or if I have to write a managed c++ dll?